# How to keep the same background on a horizontally sliding web?

Tags: background, web, slide, fixed, horizontal-scrolling

I'd like to ask if it's possible to keep the same background image while sliding on my [webpage](http://79423.w23.wedos.ws/) (using the image icons). 
I wanted to keep the background from the mainpage (somehow fix it there) and just make the content 'slide on it'. I used [this jquery - javascript](http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/horizontal-website.php) method to make the slides.

Used these old jquery function for the sliding:

```
/* jQuery.ScrollTo
/* jQuery.LocalScroll
/* Fire Horizontal Scroll */
```

(full code is on the linked page)

The 9 'slides' are put in a wrap. The  first one is the mainpage.

```
    <body>

    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="one"><p>ONE</p></div>
    <div id="two"><p>TWO</p> <a href="#one">« HOME </a> </div>
    <div id="three"><p>THREE</p> <a href="#one">« HOME </a> </div> 
    <div id="four"><p>FOUR</p> <a href="#one">« HOME </a> </div>
    <div id="five"><p>FIVE</p> <a href="#one">« HOME </a> </div>
    <div id="six"><p>SIX</p> <a href="#one">« HOME </a> </div>
    <div id="seven"><p>SEVEN</p> <a href="#one">« HOME </a> </div>
    <div id="eight"><p>EIGHT</p> <a href="#one">« HOME </a> </div>
    <div id="nine"><p>NINE</p> <a href="#one">« HOME </a> </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the interesting part of the css

```
#wrap {
min-height: 100%;
width: 900%;
overflow: hidden;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven, #eight, #nine {
width: 11.1%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}

* html {background:url(images/mainfull.jpg)}
* html #full {height:100%;}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML/JS code into your post. Readers of your question usually don't like to dig through linked websites to find the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] All you have to do is change the background position to fixed instead of absolute.

```
.background-image {
    background: url(images/mainfull.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    position: fixed;

    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;

    -moz-animation-name: fade-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    background-image: url('images/mainfull.jpg');
    background-position: center center fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```